# Arabic script not displaying in chapter headings, even though body text is fine.

Tags: fontspec, polyglossia, arabic

In the MWE below {thanks to @maïeul}, the Arabic chapter heading and chapter number does not display the Arabic font, but the body text displays fine.
It seems to be a problem with Arabic, because other languages {Russian, Hebrew} work fine.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{xunicode,metalogo,hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}    
\setotherlanguage{arabic}    
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\russianfont[Script=Cyrillic]{Linux Libertine O}    

\begin{document}
\begin{Arabic}
\chapter{كلمة}
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة
\end{Arabic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the problem seems to be the `\Makeuppercase` command which is called inside the `\chapter` command

Comment: Is adding `\setmainlanguage{arabic}` can solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments above, 
`\setmainlanguage` needs to be set to the language I want the chapters in.  This seems a sensible limitation.